# ng-init with ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display some numbers in a div using as like below

```
 <div ng-init="range=[1,10,3,4,5]" ng-repeat="n in range" >
  {{n}}
 </div>
```

It is not showing the numbers in `range`

Comment: try see any errors in console. Also as workaround just `ng-repeat="n in [1,10,3,4,5]"`

Comment: `ngInit` has a priority of 450, `ngRepeat` of 1000.

Comment: What's wrong with initializing them _in the controller_?  `$scope.range = [1,10,3,4,5]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize before ng-repeat

```
<div ng-init="range=[1,10,3,4,5]" >
<div ng-repeat="n in range" >
  {{n}}
 </div> 
</div>
```

Fiddle for solution:https://jsfiddle.net/ggbnanoL/

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the values before `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-init="range=[1,10,3,4,5]"></div>
<div ng-repeat="n in range" >
    {{n}}
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vtmc4RJ8Fb0CYPcqMm46?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

ng-init should only be used for aliasing: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Can you not initialise the range value in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ANY ng-init="range=[1,10,3,4,5]">
    </ANY>
    <div ng-repeat="n in range">
    {{n}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```